# user browse web site history data

Tags: c++

I would like to list  user connect web site link,get all history data
where can i got those data.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I'm new I'll just have to post as broad an answer as I can for your vague question.

If your goal is to get a users recent browsing history, you should just be able to look up the places where all of the mainstream browsers store their history data. I highly doubt the devs would put such insensitive information under encryption, so this shouldn't be too hard. Browsers that you should take in to consideration include Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Netscape Navigator, and all of the other Mozilla spinoffs, such as Sea Monkey.

If your goal is to establish a connection to a web server, and then download a list of data provided by the server, there is a lot of setup involved. First, you need a server. You can use something like Apache, and use the HTTP protocol for all data transmission, or if you're feeling brave, you could whip up a server of your own design. Second, you need a way to connect to this server. Since it appears you're using visual C++, WinSock would be the way to do this. There are plenty of tutorials online for WinSock, just Google away.

I hope this helps you, and best of luck to your endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is tagged "C++", I assume that your program works on local computer.

Each browser has its own format of "history storage". You will have to work on different formats if you are targeting the major browsers, e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.

For example, Firefox and Chrome stores its history in a SQLite database, while IE stores in a binary file named "index.dat".

Here are some places to start:

- Firefox :

  - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Places_database
- IE :
  http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_History_File_Format